# ubuntu software center crashes after fail install

Tags: installation, apt

I tried to install libboost-system1.42-dev package but for some reason it crashed for the first time.

Now for ANY package I try to install I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 961, in simulate
trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1085, in _simulate_helper
return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 226, in required_download
pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate file for the libboost-system1.42-dev package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

Any ideas on how to deal with the problem? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to purge `libboost-system1.42-dev` first (`sudo dpkg -P libboost-system1.42-dev`), then try again. If that works out, then reinstall and go from there.